# GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object - ARB functions not defined

Tags: opengl

The following [document](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_uniform_buffer_object.txt) doesn't contain ARB functions, for example `GetUniformBlockIndexARB`, there is defined non-ARB function `GetUniformBlockIndex`. I expect to find there ARB functions. Is it an error? In the other hand this [document](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_draw_instanced.txt) contains ARB functions, for example `DrawArraysInstancedARB`. The documentation is not consistent. Could you explain it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the extension is the same as a new feature in a later OpenGL version, they keep the function names the same (no suffix) for consistency.

See [this question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1809/opengl-compatibility-naming-conventions-and-arb-vs-ext) about ARB_framebuffer_object, and this note in ARB_uniform_buffer_object (which you linked to):

```
(v62, 2009-03-26, jon)
    - Remove ARB suffixes for consistency with other extensions
      simultaneously introduced with new GL core features, intended
      to enable those features in older drivers.
```

ARB_uniform_buffer_object is "an extension simultaneously introduced with new GL core features, intended to enable those features in older drivers".

Uniform Buffer Objects are available in OpenGL 3.1, but if your driver only supports 3.0 but not 3.1, but it can support uniform buffer objects, it may use the ARB_uniform_buffer_object extension. The functions are exactly the same, no matter whether you are using the extension, or whether you are using OpenGL 3.1.